pytest add a single skip check for all tests in TestClass based on parametrize variables
How can I move the pytest.skip() check outside so I can run it only once and not inside all tests like below.
I need the args.webhost and args.tenant from conftest.py to run the check.
class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("webhost", args.webhost)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("tenant", args.tenant)
    def test01_setup(self, ext, params, tenant, webhost):
        """ enroll user to use as passportreader """
        providers = tools.scrape.portalproviders(webhost, type='operator', tenant=tenant)
        if 'idp-passport-authenticator' not in providers:
            pytest.skip(f"skip because idp-passport-authenticator not found for tenant:{tenant}")
        :

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("webhost", args.webhost)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("tenant", args.tenant)
    def test02_passportreader(self, ext, params, tenant, webhost):
        """ test enrolled user in passportreader frontend """
        providers = tools.scrape.portalproviders(webhost, type='operator', tenant=tenant)
        if 'idp-passport-authenticator' not in providers:
            pytest.skip(f"skip because idp-passport-authenticator not found for tenant:{tenant}")
        :
    
    <more tests>
    :


